# Symfony2 - Check server-server request

Tags: symfony, request

I need to know when a request comes from a browser and when it comes from a server.

I have created an API and a listener to onKernelRequest event, I need to know what kind of request I received to execute a function or other.

How can I do this on Symfony 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A “server“ is an HTTP client just as a browser is. They only handle your websites response differently. So there’s no way to be *sure* who you are talking to. You can only check for a number of indicators.

You can examine the HTTP headers in the `Request` object. Your best bet would probably be the `User-Agent` header. But a non-browser could just as well fake the user agent header of an actual browser, so you’d only detect them if they want you to. And you’d have to prepare a list of user agents that you’d consider “servers“.